# Application cannot be provided in DomainComponent (Dagger 2)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm implementing a Sampler App using `Dagger 2` for `Dependency Injection`.

But I can't use my Services(SQLiteDatabase uses Application), since my Application can't be Provided by my AppComponent:

```
error: android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract ch.ti8m.gol.daggerchaos.persistence.SqlDatabase provideSqlDatabae();
                                                                    ^
      android.app.Application is injected at
          ch.ti8m.gol.daggerchaos.domain.di.DomainModule.provideSQLDatabase(app)
      ch.ti8m.gol.daggerchaos.persistence.SqlDatabase is provided at
          ch.ti8m.gol.daggerchaos.domain.di.DomainComponent.provideSqlDatabae()
```

**My AppModule**

```
@Module
class AppModule() {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(app: App): Application {
        return app
    }
}
```

**My AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: App)
}
```

**My DomainModule**

```
@Module
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePizzaService(pizzaDAO: PizzaDAO): PizzaService {
        return PizzaServiceImpl(pizzaDAO)
    }

    //TODO get Application form App Component
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSQLDatabase(app: Application): SqlDatabase {
        return SqlDatabase(app)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePizzaDAO(db: SqlDatabase): PizzaDAO {
        return PizzaDAO(db)
    }    
}
```

**My DomainComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, DomainModule::class])
interface DomainComponent {

    fun providePizzaService(): PizzaService
    fun provideSqlDatabae(): SqlDatabase
    fun providePizzaDAO(): PizzaDAO

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(activityMainPresenterImpl: ActivityMainPresenterImpl)
}
```

**My Application**

```
class App : Application() {

    private lateinit var domainComponent: DomainComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        domainComponent = DaggerDomainComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule())
                .application(this)
                .domainModule(DomainModule())
                .build()

        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }

    fun getDomainComponent(): DomainComponent {
        return domainComponent
    }
}
```

**Where I inject it**

```
class ActivityMainPresenterImpl(private val activityMainView: ActivityMainView) : ActivityMainPresenter {
    @Inject
    lateinit var pizzaService: PizzaService

    init {
        DaggerDomainComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
    }
...
```

I just started using Dagger 2 for Dependency Injection in Android, so I'm sure I messed up the Injection Structure.

Does anybody know what I missed or failed to implement in the proper way (I know there are lots of ways to implement DI with Dagger)?

Comment: Can you post your injection code also?

Comment: @JeelVankhede of course

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the dagger errors it looks like your DomainComponent is missing the binding for the `App` instance which is required to provide the `Application` class used in your DomainModule.

You could add a `Component.Builder` to the `DomainComponent` to provide this, as you have done with your AppComponent*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, DomainModule::class])
interface DomainComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun app(app: App): Builder
        fun build(): DomainComponent
    }
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

*Note your AppComponent has the wrong binding as it binds an `Application` rather than a `App` instance. As `AppComponent` isn't been used your probably don't need it?

When building your `DaggerDomainComponent` you would then need to provide the `App` instance.

```
DaggerDomainComponent.builder()
        .app(this) // App reference
        .build()
```

Also, it looks a bit strange you create the `DomainComponent` in your Application but then create a new `DomainComponent` to allow the presenter to inject itself - you probably want to restructure this so the same `DomainComponent` can be used for injection, creating a new component every-time will loose some of your scoping.